# Android XML dataHandler getResources() is undefined

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, datahandler

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm trying to create a dataHandler for an xml.
But I get an error: "The method getResources() is undefined for the type CasusHandler".

What am I forgetting?

```
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class CasusHandler {

    public String[] casus;

    public void setCasusArray() {
        Resources res = getResources();
        this.casus = res.getStringArray(R.array.casus);
    }

    public String[] getCasusArray() {
        return this.casus;
    }

}
```

Comment: getResources() is a method of `Context`...

Comment: You have to inject Context and then call context.getResources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResources()` is a method of `Context`. and here you can pass the `Context` reference to the method `setCasusArray()`

```
public void setCasusArray(Context context) {
   this.casus = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.casus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the Context to you class so you could call getResurces

what you should do is the following :

```
public class CasusHandler {

    public String[] casus;


    public void setCasusArray(Context context ) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        this.casus = res.getStringArray(R.array.casus);
    }

    public String[] getCasusArray() {
        return this.casus;
    }

}
```

Hope that helps